# Need REGEX to find text excluding one character inside

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a text like this:

> [mk_dropcaps char=”L”]os especialistas no dejan de insistir en ello: si quieres gozar de una buena salud bucodental.

I need a regex that matches `[mk_dropcaps char=””]`, excluding the character between quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to capture just that within the [ ] square brackets?

```
\[mk_dropcaps char="."\]
```

You may need to replace the quotes with ones you use :P

Answer (score 0):

When creating regexp you can use [utilities websites](https://regex101.com/) to help you with the task.

The answer you seek is :

```
^.*\[mk_dropcaps char=”.”\].*$
```

---

The explaination :

[image]

---

**EDIT**

```js
const regex = /^.*(\[mk_dropcaps char=”.”\]).*$/;

const str = '[mk_dropcaps char=”L”]os especialistas no dejan de insistir en ello: si quieres gozar de una buena salud bucodental.';

const ret = regex.exec(str);

console.log(ret[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work as I look https://regex101.com/r/iF9RbU/1/ this regex ^.*\[mk_dropcaps char=”.”\].*$ select all text and not only [mk_dropcaps char=""]

Comment: I've edited my post, you need to add parenthesis as in the added snippet

Comment: Simple `\[mk_dropcaps char=”.”\]` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

For your example data you could use 2 capturing groups to capture `[mk_dropcaps char=”` and `”]` using:

`(\[mk_dropcaps char=”)[^”]+(”\])` or `(\[[^”]+”)[^”]+(”\])`

[Regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/xApuen/2) [Regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/cwtuCv/2)

Then use the capturing groups `\1\2` to get `[mk_dropcaps char=””]`